# Unity3D : Is it possible to display a running mobile app on a texture?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

here I come with a somewhat strange question.

Let's say I have an Android app and the source code of course. This app may be made with Unity or simply with Android Studio.

Now, let's say I have a second Unity project, with a simple scene that contains a "screen" in a 3d space/room.

I was courious... Would it be possible to run the first app on the "big screen" inside the second app?

After googling quite a while, I understand it probably is not, but I wanted to hear other ideas beside mine on this topic ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a discussion, so next time please use the forums for topics like these.

However, about your question - any modern OS will prevent you from interacting with a running app other than accessing their storage or through notifications.

*Option:* you can use a browser in-game. Never done it myself but I'm sure there must be some libraries for Unity. You can have all the page data stored locally.